# Computer won't boot into Windows 7 after hibernation with USB flash drive

Tags: windows-7, boot, hibernate

My Computer hibernated with USB flash drive connected now It start to boot and stops at a black screen with a blinking cursor. I think it tries to boot from the flash drive.

Is there way to return to windows without losing my work?

https://thumbs.gfycat.com/SilkyValidKudu-size_restricted.gif

Comment: How much did you wait for it?

Comment: Try your boot option key [Function key], most of the time it is F10 or F12 depending on your computer's BIOS. Choose to boot from your hard disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your boot order in the Bios so that removable drives are checked after your Hard drive. This should negate the problem you are seeing.

How you specifically do this is dependant on your motherboard. But in general, use <kbd>delete</kbd> or <kbd>F1</kbd> to get into the bios. From here look for something along like `device boot order` and set it from there.